# Start Windows Batch file using python wxpython Button click Event

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to start a windows batch file using python wxpython button click event.

```
import wx
import subprocess


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ Dervice new class of Frame"""
    def __init__ (self, parent, title)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(410,355))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)           
        startbutton = wx.Button(panel, label="Start", pos=(200,70), size=(80,25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.StartClicked, startbutton)


    def StartClicked(self, event):
        print "Session started"
        self.filepath="C:\\cygwin64\\Sipp_3.2\\Auto.bat"
        subprocess.call(self.filepath)
        print "Session ended"


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, "CallGenerator")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

And below is output on each times, when i click the "Start" Button.

```
>Session started
>Session ended
>Session started
>Session ended
```

Code doesn't open the batch file. But when i execute the via command prompt,the batch file is executed through the command prompt.

I'm using pyscripter and How to open the batch file as a new window?

Similarly, if the batch file contains continous ping (ping ipaddress -t), the GUI becomes crashed.

Now what is the solution for my two problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program probably is calling the batch file but because you do not redirect the process's stdout/stderr, you do not see what it is doing. You will probably want to use the `subprocess` module's `communicate` method to get the output from the batch file and update the GUI with that information.

You mentioned that the batch file runs a long running process. This is going to block the GUI's mainloop, which is why the UI becomes unresponsive. If you used `popen` instead, you might be able to get around that, however the proper solution is to put the subprocess call inside a thread and then return the result from the thread to the UI via one of wx's thread-safe methods, such as `wx.CallAfter` or `wx.PostEvent`.

See the following articles for more information:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks